# Express is serving some static files but not others

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to display an image on a webpage, but express seems to be unable to serve the image.

It won't display on the page and going to http://localhost:3000/images/login.jpg (where it should be accessible) does not show the image in the browser. Interestingly, I can access a bootstrap stylesheet at http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.min.css

[Project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbD36.png)

I've tried both of the following approaches in app.js:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I receive a 404 error when trying to access http://localhost:3000/images/login.jpg

Comment: What does the `<img>` tag look like in the HTML?  Is the path on that tag `/images/login.jpg`?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's <img src="/images/login.jpg"/>

Comment: Is there a permissions issue with the `images` folder?  Like you, I don't see how a css file can work, but not an images file.

Comment: @jfriend00 No permission issues as far as I can tell. Express is running with `sudo` privileges, and the image opens just fine if I navigate to it through chrome with its file path (i.e `file:///C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/home/joe/police_system/public/images/login.jpg`) Also, if I put the login.jpg in the `css` directory with the stylesheet that successfully loads, I still cannot access it using `http://localhost:3000/css/login.jpg`

Comment: I can't really tell from your file system image.  Are `/css` and `/images` at the same level of the file system with the same parent?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, they're both in the `public` folder, which contains `css`, `images`, `js`, and `stylesheets`

Comment: Do you have any other routes that could be getting in the way?  Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.  If it were me, I'd probably step through the `express.static()` middleware during one of these requests in order to see why it's not finding the desired file.

Comment: @jfriend00 Turns out you were right about the permissions thing. Thank you! See my solution

Comment: OK, glad you found the permission issue as that was one of the few issues left I could imagine it could be.

Answer (score 0):

So I feel dumb. The problem comes from the way I'm running express - I'm running it from an Ubuntu shell within Windows 10. I dropped `login.jpg` into my project through Windows 10's explorer, and Unix wasn't able to access it. Nothing I could do in Unix made the file visible to Unix. I'm running the server with Powershell now, and the problem is fixed.